# Add Button on Last Index of Cell programmatically

Tags: ios4, sdk, uitableview

I am working on an app in which I require a functionality of load more results. I want add a button programmatically in the last index of table view if any one has some idea how to di it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the table footer to add the button. This way it will always be on the bottom of the table and it won't mess up you cell count.

In `-(void)viewDidLoad`, you can add something like this:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = myview;
```

where myview is a UIView containing a button, or simply just a UIButton (UIButton is a view).